# Node.js blog post add comment not working

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, controllers

### When I add a comment to any blog post it doesn't work. This is a normal Node.js MVC controller which is linked to route:

```
    commentBlog(req, res) {

      const comment = {
        comment: req.body.comment,
        author: req.params.id
      }

      Comment.create(comment, (error, comment) =>  {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        } else {
          Blog.findById(req.params.id, (error, blog) => {
            blog.comments.push(comment);
            console.log(comment);
            blog.save((error, savedBlog) => {
              if (error) {
                console.log(error);
              } else{
              res.redirect('/blogs/' + blog._id);
            }
        })
         })
        }
      })
      };
```

---

(  this is the model )
    --------------------
    const mongoose     = require('mongoose'),
          Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

```
var commentSchema = new Schema({
    author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user' },
    comment: {type: String},
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    blog: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'blog' }
});

var Comment = mongoose.model('comment', commentSchema);

module.exports = Comment;
```

---

```
this is the ejs file
---------------------
<body>

 <% if(blog) { %>

<form action="/blogs/<%= blog._id %>/comment" method="POST">
    <textarea name="comment[text]"
        rows="10" cols="50">Write something here
    </textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Post comment">
    </form>
 <% } %>
```

```
**i don't know why it doesn't display when i add like to any post it just
```

### don't work**

Comment: You have add the result and question correctly.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? You need to be more specific.

Comment: It's not the problem but your async functions doesn't return anything on error. Add more details regarding the errors if you want help

Comment: when i add comment it doesn't display anywhere, normally comment  or like  should be display  close to a blog post

Comment: If anyone know where  i can find any open source where a simple node.js  mvc finished project on comment and like blog post please i will be waiting for help on this.

Comment: Well, you are not displaying the blog content in your `ejs` file

Answer (score 0):

Well, you were not displaying the blog content in your `ejs` file. Only rendering the form. You should render the blog fields for them to display. Below is an example to show the blog title( provided there is a title field in the blog object).

```
    <body>

     <% if(blog) { %>
    <h2><%= blog.title %> </h2>

    <form action="/blogs/<%= blog._id %>/comment" method="POST">
        <textarea name="comment[text]"
            rows="10" cols="50">Write something here
        </textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Post comment">
        </form>
<% } %>
```

You can then display the other fields in your blog object using the example above.

Comment: Thanks allot but doesn't work is there any related open source to view a clear idea on node.js mvc blog post with likes will be very much appreciated